# Add a new array to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state, react-context

I am using context api for state management
I have set an initial state for students: null and tags: []
students is an array of objects with data like this:

```
[
{
 "id": 1,
 "city": "some city",
 "name" : "some name",
 "colors" : [
             "1": "blue",
             "2" : "red"
            ],
 "age": "some age"
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "city": "some city",
 "name" : "some name",
 "colors" : [
             "1": "green",
             "2" : "yellow"
            ],
 "age": "some age"
}
]
```

The tag array will be like this

```
{
 "studentId": 1,
 "tag": "some tag",
},
{
 "studentId": 2,
 "tag": "some tag",
},
{
 "studentId": 2,
 "tag": "some tag",
},
]
```

Now I want to add the objects in the tag array to their matching objects in student array.
example, the student with id number 2, he has two tags with his id. i want the tag array with studentId 2 to be added as an array to the student object of that particular id..Dont know if i am making sense.

My state file

```
 const addTag = async tag => {

    try {

        dispatch({ 
            type: ADD_TAG, 
            payload: tag
           })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ 
            type: STUDENT_ERROR ,
            payload: error
           })
    }
}
```

My reducer

```
 case ADD_TAG:
            return {
                ...state,
                
                tags: [...state.tags, action.payload],
 
            }
```

I am only populating the tags state..but i want to also do so for the students state.
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply copy the students array (so you don't mutate it directly), find the index of student object in question, and then add the tags to it.

```
case ADD_TAG:
   let studentCopies = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.students));
   let index = studentCopies.findIndex(s => s.id === action.payload.studentId);


   if (index > -1) {
      // if student object is in array, then add tag to student's tag array

     if (studentCopies[index].tags) {
       studentCopies[index].tags = [...studentCopies[index].tags, action.payload];
     } else {
        studentCopies[index].tags = [action.payload]
     }
   }  
    

   return {
     ...state,
     students: studentCopies,
     tags: [...state.tags, action.payload]
   }
```

Comment: TypeError: studentCopies[index].tags is not iterable
 The error i am getting now

Comment: Oh, if you don't have any students to start with that makes sense

Comment: I updated by example. If students is null, then the error you got makes sense because you can't iterate over null. Do you want to be able to add tags before you can add students?

Comment: i THINK it is beacuse there is no tags array inside the students array..
could that be the reason?
Becuase i have students...it even gets the index from your code..it works fine up till studentCopies[index].tags = [...studentCopies[index].tags, action.payload];

Comment: let me try the updated one
The students exists..it is not null. but by default there is no tags array in the students array.. so i want it such that once we add a tag, a tag array is created in the student array matching the id. Wowww it workeedddddddddd

Comment: I just updated it again. Now I'm checking if the student object has a tags array. If it doesn't I add one. If it does, I just add to it